# Parallel processing of large dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, multiprocessing

I have a large Pandas DataFrame with columns a and b (kind of coordinates in floats) and column c (values), which has to be binned and summarized over a certain interval of steps in the columns a and b. The order of the result is relevant, since a and b simulate coordinates where samples have been taken with the value c. In the next step, the results would be reshaped to an image and processed further.

This can be solved using nested loops (see below), however, it obviously does not scale well with larger datasets or smaller step sizes.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random(int(10E7))
b = np.random.random(int(10E7))
c = np.random.random(int(10E7))

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b, 'values': c})

stepsize = 0.1

means = []

T1 = time.time()
for j in np.arange(0,1,stepsize):
    for i in np.arange(0,1,stepsize):
        selection = df[ (df.a > i) & (df.a <= i+stepsize) &  (df.b > j) & (df.b <= j+stepsize) ]
        means.append(selection['values'].mean())   
T2 = time.time()
```

I have been wondering, how this can be resolved using `multiprocessing` (or `multithreading`?).
Therefore, I have set up the following code, though I am stuck: I am not sure, if the meanAB code is setup correctly and if the `multiprocessing` has been initiated correctly.

```
stepsize = 0.01 # smaller stepsize
A_vals = list(np.arange(0,1,stepsize))
B_vals = list(np.arange(0,1,stepsize))

def meanByAB(A,B):
    # loaded df and stepsize globally. Does it make sense?!
    selection = df[ (df.a > A) & (df.a <= A+stepsize) &  (df.b > B) & (df.b <= B+stepsize)  ]
    mean = np.mean(selection['values'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    T1 = time.time()
    p = mp.Process(target=meanByAB,args=(A_values,B_values,) # tried many things here. yields ValueError
    p.start()
    p.join()
    T2 = time.time()
```

Comment: Is the order of values in the 'mean' list relevant?

Comment: do you realize you're taking the mean of all the column's values?

Comment: The order is relevant: the results are going to be reordered to an array and processed further. -- Also the values part is changed. I hope this clarifies the issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. The results are not ordered, because I don't understand which is the right sorting to apply. However, each element of the list of results is a tuple composed of: (mean, A, B) where A and B are the values you specify. A posteriori, you can sort the values based on A and B, or by mean if you need it:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Array, Queue
# import multiprocessing as mp
from threading import Thread
import threading as th
from queue import Queue
import time

def worker(df, q_input, q_output, stepsize):
  while True:
    A = q_input.get()
    if A == 'DONE':
      break
    for i, B in enumerate(np.arange(0,1,stepsize)): 
      selection = df[ (df.a > A) & (df.a <= A+stepsize) &  (df.b > B) & (df.b <= B+stepsize)  ]
      mean = np.mean(selection.values)
      q_output.put((mean, A, B))

def dump_queue(queue):
    result = []
    while not queue.empty():
      result.append(queue.get(timeout=0.01))
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
  start_time = time.time()
  start_initialization = time.time()
  NUM_THREADS = 4
  a = np.random.random(int(10E7))
  b = np.random.random(int(10E7))
  c = np.random.random(int(10E7))
  df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b, 'values': c})
  stepsize = 0.1
  means = []

  q_input = Queue()
  for j in np.arange(0,1,stepsize):
    q_input.put(j)

  for _ in range(NUM_PROCESSES):
    q_input.put('DONE')

  q_output = Queue()

  print(f"Initialization terminates in {time.time() - start_initialization}")
  processes = [Thread(target=worker, args=(df, q_input, q_output, stepsize), name=f"Worker-{i}") for i in range(NUM_THREADS)]
  for p in processes:
    p.start()

  for p in processes:
    p.join()

  print(f"Finished in  {time.time() - start_time}")
  result = dump_queue(q_output)
  print(result)
  print(len(result))
```

---

**EDIT**

The edited version uses multi-threading instead of multiprocessing: multi-threading is lighter than multiprocessing, so I think it should be the best choice in this problem

Comment: I have tested your answer using a stepsize of 0.1 to compare it with the approach using nested for loops. The nested for loops complete the task in approx 40 seconds whereas the multiprocessing approach takes 120 seconds. Shouldn't be the multiprocessing approach the faster one?

Comment: You are right! Multiprocessing has a lots of overhead, I'm going to edit my previous solution using multithreading instead. I my laptop it runs much faster and in this context I think is the best choice